# How to keep the values around a number?

Tags: python

This question is regarding python.
In my list, I have these values :`[0.0, 0.3, 0.6, 1.0]`
What should I do to only keep the value around the specific number?
For example, I want to keep the values around `0.3` so that in the list, I will only have `[0.0, 0.3, 0.6]`

I forgot to say that these data is not in ascending order, but it is in random order. Example: [0.0, 0.6, 1.0, 0.3]. And if I only want to keep one number bigger and one lesser than a specific number, what should I do? I shouldn't sort it at all.

Example: From [0.0, 0.6, 1.0, 0.3], and if I only want to keep the values around 0.6, so that I will only have [0.0, 0.3, 0.6]

Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: Are you looking to keep the surrounding numbers by value? Or by surrounding elements of the list?

Answer (score 0):

```
data = [0.0, 0.3, 0.6, 1.0]
search_for = 0.3

# make sure value is in list
if search_for in data:

    # get index of value
    index = data.index(search_for)

    # get array slice to include index - 1, index, & index + 1
    slice = data[index-1:index+2]

    print(slice)
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps filtering by:

```
def condition(x):
    return not abs(x-0.3) > 0.3
```

As to keep the items that are no more than 0.3 away from 0.3

Comment: I believe OP was asking for surrounding elements. Not by values. (I'm asking for clarification though)

Answer (score 0):

```py
def keepAround(data, number):
    if number in data and len(data) > 2:
        ind = data.index(number)
        return data[ind-1:ind+2]
    return data
```

Does this work?

Basically, it first checks if the number is in the list you have and if the length of data is at least 3. It will return the list otherwise.
If it does pass the condition, it will grab the index of the number in the list and slice it so that only the surrounding numbers (and the number itself) stays.